# Prevent unauthenticated route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a Laravel 5.2 application with the following route :

```
api/vehicle
api/note
api/task
```

I am using AngularJS and I want to prevent unauthorized access of url http://localhost:8000/api/note (only authenticated users can see the response).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you try to rephrase your question, as it is not clear what you want help with. Please have a look at and follow [these](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Comment: What have you got so far ? This is handled by the server side.. 401* error.. not authorized.. Your client side just needs to react to it..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `auth` middleware either in routes or in your controller.

```
class ApiController extends Controller {
   public function __construct() {
      $this->middleware('auth');
   }
}
```

OR

```
Route::group([middleware => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'api'], function(){
    // your routes here
});
```